# Drawing a right triangle (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm having a bit of an issue. I'm trying to make this program output a right triangle based on the height and symbol that is specified by the user, but whenever I enter the symbol and height desired the program will output the correct shape, but upside-down. I've been having some difficulties getting a firm grasp of loops and through trial and error, this is the best I could come up with thus far. Could someone help a brother out, please. Thank yous in advance.

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')

for i in range (len(triangle_char)):
    for j in range (triangle_height):
        print((triangle_char) * triangle_height )
        triangle_height -= 1
```

This code will return this output when character is '*' and height is 5:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

The expected output when those values are entered should be:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Can you show your required output? Also what about length of base of triangle?

Comment: The expected output when the character is '#' and the height is 5 should be a right triangle comprised of the character '#' with a height and base of 5.

Comment: You see whats happening. You are getting reversed output. Can you debug the code and find out what is the source for this. [Hint: 5 chars are printed in first line instead of 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your loops are both off; you are assigning values to `i` and `j` and not using them.

Second, the first loop is useless. If you input 3 characters it will repeat the block 3 times, but the variable `triangle_height` is decreased to 0 at the first pass, so nothing will be printed at the next iteration.
Just remove this line

Third: You say that you need the triangle reversed, so, instead of decreasing `triangle_height`, use the value you assing to `j` in the for loop and forget about decreasing the variable. 
Since range starts counting from 0 you need to add 1 to it in the print statement:

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character: ')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height: '))
print('')

for j in range (triangle_height):
    print((triangle_char) * (j + 1))
```

I have also replaced `/n` with a space in the input() methods because it looked pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this :

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character: ')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height: '))
print('')

j = 0;

while j <= triangle_height :
    print triangle_char * j
    j += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as a script. I assumed that multiple input characters meant multiple output triangles. Also, that height:0 means zero lines in each triangle.

Tricky thing I learned today is that `int("20.0")` doesn't convert to 20; it raises an exception. The code works around that by converting to float first.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def triangles(characters, height):
    # We could call int(height) here except that int("20.0") for example raises
    # an error even though there is a pretty clear integer value. To get around
    # that, attempt to convert to float first.
    try:
        lines = float(height)
    except ValueError:
        # If we raise here, the error is like: cannot convert to float. That's
        # confusing, so we let it go.
        lines = height

    # If the value can't be converted to int, this raises an error like: cannot
    # convert to int. If it had already converted to float, this rounds down.
    lines = int(lines)

    for character in characters:
        # Loop will execute no times if lines==0, once if lines==1 and so on.
        for line in range(1, lines + 1):
            print(str(character) * line)
        print("")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        triangles(input("Enter characters: "), input("Enter height: "))
    except ValueError as error:
        print("Couldn't print triangles:", error)
```

Edit: Added sample output.

```
$ ./triangles.py 
Enter characters: jk
Enter height: 8
j
jj
jjj
jjjj
jjjjj
jjjjjj
jjjjjjj
jjjjjjjj

k
kk
kkk
kkkk
kkkkk
kkkkkk
kkkkkkk
kkkkkkkk

$ ./triangles.py 
Enter characters: .
Enter height: 3.0
.
..
...

$ ./triangles.py 
Enter characters: f
Enter height: 3.7
f
ff
fff

$ ./triangles.py 
Enter characters: duff
Enter height: duff
Couldn't print triangles: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'duff'
```